# URL Token with Identity Server 4

Tags: c#, url, token, identityserver4

Is it possible to use a URL token with Identity Server? We need to be able to give users "magic links". This link contains a token on the URL in a querystring. We need to be able to use that token and authenticate the particular request.

Comment: It seems it is possbile, see this discussion ans sample https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/issues/2716

Comment: I'll have a read - many thanks